# PAM LDAP add user to mail group

Tags: ldap, pam, groups

I've mount a LDAP Server (Debian) using PAM to let my clients connecto via SSH. I'd like to add them to the mail group o let them use the mail somehow.
I've tried to create a new CN with gidnumber=8 (mail gid is 8), but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to add ldap users to groups in the linux server?